# unban array of ids discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Code:

```js
if (command === "ubm") {
    console.log(chalk.yellow`You ran a command: ubm`);
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(args[0]);
    const me = config.ownerID;
    await guild.fetchBans(me).then((g) => {
        g.members.unban(me);
    });
}
```

Error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchBans' of undefined`

Does anyone know what's wrong with this? The command looks like this:

-ubm <Server ID>

Note that `config.ownerID` is an Array of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `fetch` the bans of your server. Simply use a `message.guild.members.unban(id)`

**Example:**

```js
if(command === "ubm"){
    console.log((chalk.yellow)`You ran a command: ubm`);
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(args[0]); //I would suggest adding some error trapping here, as if the guild doesnt exist the bot will throw
    const me = config.ownerID[0]; //get necessary element in array
    message.guild.members.unban(me); 
}
```

Make sure you use semicolons where necessary - it saves irritating errors later

Comment: i already tried that to which i get this: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [BAN_RESOLVE_ID]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban.

Comment: From what I can gather, your `config.ownerID` property is not working properly, try console logging it to make sure it is a value, not an object

Comment: its an array of ids, ['id1', 'id2'] like that, what this code does it checks for the first id in the array and stops the progress when the first one isnt banned, im trying to figure out how to let it unban whatever is banned instead of dying when the first one isnt banned

Comment: okay, that will not work - if it is an array, you need to call which element you want to use - I will update my code yet again